# Select all in a string array - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I currently have a tableview where I wanna insert some data (Which is taken from another ViewController) Everything works great, except one thing.

When I retrieve the data I'm using the code:

```
let txt = pointsTxt(person: nameArray[0], points: countedArray[0])
```

Which means, it will only select the very first index and insert into the table view. But I need it to select all available indexes.
Instead of inserting 1 value into the tableview, I need it to insert ALL data from the arrays.

This is my code:

```
func createArray() -> [pointsTxt]
{
    var tempTxt: [pointsTxt] = []

    let txt = pointsTxt(person: nameArray[0], points: countedArray[0])

    tempTxt.append(txt)


    self.list = tempTxt
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    return list
}
```

Comment: Can I assume that `nameArray` and `countedArray` have the same length?

Comment: @Sweeper Ah sorry for not mentioning that. Yes, they are the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `pointsTxt` is a struct or class, you could [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip), then `map`:

```
tempTxt = zip(nameArray, countedArray).map { pointsTxt(person: $0.0, points: $0.1) }
```

This loops through the two arrays at the same time, and converts each pair of values to a `pointsTxt`.

Your whole method could look like this:

```
func createArray() -> [pointsTxt]
{
    self.list = zip(nameArray, countedArray).map { pointsTxt(person: $0.0, points: $0.1) }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    return list
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Do you mind explaining what the "zip" does? Just for future needs. Thanks a lot! (I'll accept as soon as possible)

Comment: @Putte It combines two sequences into a single sequence of tuples. See the linked documentation for more info.